# Java: Serializing RSA public key with GSON

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, instance, gson

I am trying to make encrypted communication between client and server. When server starts its public and private RSA keys are generated. Client asks server for its public key and server sends the key for client. Server sends public key in JSON format:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String key = gson.toJson(pubKey);
```

And on client I'm trying to obtain key with:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
PublicKey pubServerKey = gson.fromJson(responce_json, PublicKey.class);
```

But I'm getting exception as described [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html)

So I'm trying to define an InstanceCreator for pubServerKey like in code below

```
class PublicKeyInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<PublicKey> {
    public PublicKey createInstance(Type type) {
        return new PublicKey(Object.class, 0L);
    }
 }
```

But this time I'm getting syntax error : Cannot instantiate the type PublicKey

Can you suggest me how to solve this problem?
In this situation is Json is a good way to pass RSA public key from server to client?

Could appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for my problem. Instead of passing PublicKey to json I  passing modulus and public exponent in json. After I obtained PublicKey on client side by using KeyFactory. More detailed description is [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml)